# mongoose connection connectTimeoutMS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I can't seem to get my mongo connection to timeout faster than the default.

```
var databaseUrl = 'mongodb://localhost/doesnotexist';
var options = { server: { connectTimeoutMS: 10000 } };

var db = mongoose.connect(databaseUrl, options, function (err) {
    ...
}
```

I am trying to simulate the DB going offline to test the failover to message queues, but can't seem to get this to work.

Any help with this would be great, thanks.

Comment: do you want to affect the timeout on the opening of the initial connection, or of each query? If the latter you want `socketTimeoutMS`

Answer (score 3):

connectTimeoutMS is a socket option which is specified like so:

```
var databaseUrl = 'mongodb://localhost/doesnotexist';
var options = { server: { socketOptions: { connectTimeoutMS: 10000 }}};

var db = mongoose.connect(databaseUrl, options, function (err) {

})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  Unfortunately this has not altered the behavior.

Comment: I wrote a quick test case for this: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1201