# connectTimeoutMS in mongoose doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently trying to optimize my server, stopped the MongoDB server to test the timeout behaviour and noticed a strange issue(?) which happens in Mongoose 6.4.1.

Basically, the default timeout of MongoDB is 30000ms (30 seconds) and I set it to 7000 (7 seconds) through `connectTimeoutMS` in the `mongoose.connect` options, but it doesn't respect this value and times out at exactly 30s, which is the default.

My connection code:

```
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost/${process.env.DB_NAME}`, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  connectTimeoutMS: 7000 // Also tried to use together with 'socketTimeoutMS'
});
```

After running and waiting way longer than 7s:

```
MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
```

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168013/mongoose-connection-connecttimeoutms) and tried to use:

```
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost/${process.env.DB_NAME}`, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  connectTimeoutMS: 7000,
  server: { socketOptions: { connectTimeoutMS: 7000 }}
});
```

But this seems to be outdated, as Mongoose complains:

```
the server/replset/mongos/db options are deprecated, all their options are supported at the top level of the options object [poolSize,ssl,sslValidate,sslCA,sslCert,sslKey,sslPass,sslCRL,autoReconnect,noDelay,keepAlive,keepAliveInitialDelay,connectTimeoutMS,family,socketTimeoutMS,reconnectTries,reconnectInterval,ha,haInterval,replicaSet,secondaryAcceptableLatencyMS,acceptableLatencyMS,connectWithNoPrimary,authSource,w,wtimeout,j,forceServerObjectId,serializeFunctions,ignoreUndefined,raw,bufferMaxEntries,readPreference,pkFactory,promiseLibrary,readConcern,maxStalenessSeconds,loggerLevel,logger,promoteValues,promoteBuffers,promoteLongs,domainsEnabled,checkServerIdentity,validateOptions,appname,auth,user,password,authMechanism,compression,fsync,readPreferenceTags,numberOfRetries,auto_reconnect,minSize,monitorCommands,retryWrites,retryReads,useNewUrlParser,useUnifiedTopology,serverSelectionTimeoutMS,useRecoveryToken,autoEncryption]
```

and it also times out at the default value of 30000ms.

Is this really an issue or am I forgetting something? If it is indeed an issue, I'll file a bugreport on their repo/page, but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Definitely looks like a bug.  I am seeing the same behavior.  Looks like it is related to the `useUnifiedTopology: true`.  If I remove that, then the shorter timeout works.

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem related to `mongodb` client used by `mongoose`, so we need to wait for mongo team to solve it :(